# Which one to use: HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap with Future values JAVA?

Tags: java, hashmap, executorservice

basically we tend to use ConcuttentHashMap in multi-threading environment. My current code is like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
Map<String, Future<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Future<String>>();
myMap.put("SomeValue", executor.submit(() -> return callAndReturnStringMethod("SomeValue"));
myMap.put("AnotheValue", executor.submit(() -> return callAndReturnStringMethod("AnotheValue"));
...
....
```

I just want to store the future object for the async thread calls corresponding to the passed String as Key in the map.

My first question: Will it be good to use HashMap and not ConcurrentHashMap while dealing with Future object? Should I use ConcurrentHashMap in this scenario?
Second question: What could be the trade offs if I use latter one?

Comment: what is your access to the map like? do you modify it in concurrent threads? that's the point here, not the values you store in it

Comment: Thanks @eis, Map values are not getting modified. the callable method #callAndReturnStringMethod is performing some set of operations and returning String values. So, if I am not wrong, if we are not modifying the values concurrently we do not have to necesaarily use COncurrentHashMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying that

> Map values are not getting modified.

so there should be no reason to choose ConcurrentHashMap. ConcurrentHashMap is meant to provide thread-safety and atomicity of operations across threads, which neither you are needing.

The tradeoffs are that you're paying the price for thread-safe/atomic operations when you don't need them. As to how much that actually is, it depends on your app.

Related threads

- [Performance ConcurrentHashmap vs HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378310/performance-concurrenthashmap-vs-hashmap)
- [Are there any drawbacks with ConcurrentHashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951676/are-there-any-drawbacks-with-concurrenthashmap)

Comment: Nice and clean answer eis. But there is a SonarQube rule and many discussion threads (like those you linked) of using the concurrent hash map even if there is no concurrency since Java introduced it. Concurrent hash map has very little to no overhead compared to normal hash map when data set is small, when there is more reads than writes, with the benefits of ensuring thread safety even if the code gets refactored towards this direction, as more frameworks tends to use a multi thread model (AKKA, Reactor, etc...) I think your "it depends on your app" is a good summary

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

Use an `EnumMap` and transform your `SomeValue/AnotherValue` to `enum`s. It will be faster to build, faster to search and more compact to store. I see zero reasons to use any concurrent data structure if you do not plan to alter the `ConcurrentHashMap` *itself*, concurrently.