# creating hashmap object will prevent the map from being needed to be synchronized?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

in my webapp as soon as user log in i am creating a hashmap object in the login Action class and storing the map values specific to the user and than putting the map in session attribute. Than i am using this session in further jsp pages where i am updating the  map of the user. like this ::: code here in LoginAction.

```
   Map map = new Hashmap();         
   map.put(a1,valueA);        
   map.put(b1,valueB);        
   session.setAttribute("map",map);
```

Please note that This is happening every time the user is logging into the web application. So question is: Do this map need to be synchronized? OR it will work since I am creating the Map object every time user login in and than putting it in session for that user?

Answer (score 0):

Every web application can fire multiple request at the server at the same time. So, objects in session must be synchronized in case they are updated at the same time by different requests. The best option would be to change `HashMap` for [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: Is not a new object is getting created at every request, so still synchronization needed ?

Comment: @gSingh I don't understand what do you mean by your comment. If this map is created at user logging and its state can be modified on some requests done by this session (e.g. `map.put`, `map.remove`, etc.) then this instance should be synchronized.

Comment: when every user logged in, a map is getting created specific to that user and session... so any state change to that map should effect to the map in that session only. If in between other user logged in a new Map will be created and new session will be there for the second user. Is this correct ?

Comment: @gSingh that is correct. The problem is, for example, you open a session in a browser that allows tabs like Chrome, then a user may open the application in two tabs, and perform requests from both tabs, which generate two threads on the same session. So, to avoid any synchronization modification problem, change the `Map` for a synchronized implementation **or** store all the variables from the map directly into session.

Comment: Thanks Luiggi..so if i used ConcurrentHashmap and i am having key as string and Value as ArrayList...Than i think i have to synchronized List also in ConcurrentHashmap  ?  also, if i change every where in my code from HashMap to ConcurrentHashMap ----will the performance get effected drastically ? if i take the example of yours as you said browser in two tabs ...so what will happen now in the second tab the user open--will that be only scroll and scroll until the first tab request completes ?

Comment: @gSingh check [Performance ConcurrentHashmap vs HashMap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1378310/1065197) for a performance evaluation on this. Anyway, from the given scenario, it could delay some ms, it shouldn't be more than 200 in a stress test (as far as I'm concerned and your server has a decent hardware).

Comment: Thanks Luiggi..one more query please....So if we forgot about single user attempting with two tabs in browser at once..What about different users logged in at same time ? so in that case my scenerio will work fine without concurrentHashMap right ? i need concurrenthashmap  just because a single user can try logging two or more times at once ...right ?

Comment: Different clients (browsers, web crawlers, etc) have a single dedicated session, so there won't be any problem.

Comment: so in the beginning of this discussion you answer this "Every web application can fire multiple request at the server at the same time. So, objects in session must be synchronized in case they are updated at the same time by different requests. The best option would be to change HashMap for ConcurrentHashMap."                                                                                                                           Did you mean only the single user attempting the multiple request from same browser here ?