# Snapshot vs Clone in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Could someone please highlight the different between "Snapshot" vs "Clone" in the context of ConcurrentHashMap.
How a snapshot iterator different from an iterator that iterates over the copy of underlying data-structure.

Comment: clone is a duplicate of the ConcurrentHashMap. But Snapshot is creating new instance and add all form original map to new one.

have a look of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782319/java-how-to-take-static-snapshot-of-concurrenthashmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are just confused between those two name. Basically they are the same thing. Any iterator will contain a definite state of the collection/maps , so the name is only different but working will be the same. Though here can be different ways to implement those iterators having performance impacts . Please refer here "http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_8_copy_on_write.shtml"