# Concurrent access to Java Maps not using ConcurrentHashMap for Scalability purpose

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, scalability, atomic

I have a provider class that associates an object of mine to a string; in a few words, my provider wraps a (let's say `Map<String, Object>`) and has the 3 following operations:

- `Object get(String key)`: massively run by many threads
- `void add(String key, Object obj)`: run by a single thread
- `void remove(String key)`: run by the same single thread than `add`

While the `get()` operation needs to be fast and scalable, the `add()` and `remove()` operations does not have strong performance requirements

I would like to avoid to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` as it will certainly leads to scalability issues

So my idea is to wrap a single `HashMap` and do it such as:

- my `get()` operation does a `HashMap.get()`
- my `add()` operation

  - makes a copy of the original `HashMap`
  - adds the new element to the copied `HashMap`
  - does the following affectation `originalHashMap = copiedHashMap`
- my `remove()` operation *(almost the same)*

  - makes a copy of the original `HashMap`
  - removes the wanted element from the copied `HashMap`
  - does the following affectation `originalHashMap = copiedHashMap`

It seems to me that this way of doing is perfectly scalable. What do you think of it?

I think that for my development, I need to wrap my `Map` attribute in an `AtomicReference<>`: what do you think of that?

Thank you for your help

Comment: "as it will certainly leads to scalability issues" please elaborate. I'm always interested in hearing the evidence behind things that are deemed certain by people.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378310/performance-concurrenthashmap-vs-hashmap

Comment: No, don't do what you're trying to do. Instead, use ConcurrentHashMap. The scalability issues you're talking about are imaginary unless otherwise demonstrably shown to cause a problem (which they have not).

Comment: Unless you actually have evidence that `ConcurrentHashMap` isn't going to solve your problem, you should stick with that.  This looks like a case of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: This was a valuable question to me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seriously confused here. You say you want to avoid scalability issues, and your solution is to copy your entire map on every write command?

You may or may not be aware of this, but that's essentially what ConcurrentHashMap does under the hood. Only it does it in such a way that it only does it for a small part of the map that is being written to, and it only performs the copy when it absolutely has to. And it was written by some of the smartest minds in the industry, and has been extensively tested both in the lab and in the wild.

So instead of writing your own which is almost certainly going to be slower and have orders of magnitude more bugs, why not just go with ConcurrentHashMap?

Seriously, this is a solved problem, friend.

Comment: All true, but *You say you want to avoid scalability issues, and your solution is to copy your entire map on every write command?* Actually, that approach can make sense, if writes are relatively rare and reads are so intense that the performance hit reads take for any write are not acceptable.  I'd say, though, that without actual evidence that's the case, `ConcurrentHashMap` should be the solution.  Then, it's "Buy faster/more hardware".  Only after that fails is the solution "Write my own".

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you want to copy the entire thing on concurrent write, then you just need to `new ConcurrentHashMap<>(1);` and boom that's what it does - it splits it into 1 read-write isolated partition. In general, you want to use `ConcurrentHashMap<>(numProcessors)` or, just use the default of 16 and call it a day.

Comment: Oh, I agree with everything you say.  I'm just not going to completely rule out that the poster has some weird corner case where the out-of-the-box implementation doesn't meet some very stringent performance requirement, despite there being no evidence of that posted yet.  I've at times spent years for customers working on those types of cases, and the performance bottlenecks always seemed to be in completely unexpected code.  I'd have code and think "The bottleneck is going to be here, so I better do this right."  Too many times I wasn't even close. And it wasn't because of my earlier effort.

Answer (score -1):

OK,

Thank you for your contribution. I was sure that `ConcurrentHashMap` was not able to scale so I imagined the design explained above... but I was wrong! In fact what I had in mind was rather the behavior of SynchronizedHashMap.

FYI, I found this interesting page: https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/concurrenthashmap_scalability.shtml

Once again, thank you